# Retrieve all children with specified parentid

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have this table design.I want to get all his children in specified parentid,but I am having problem in how to filter and get all his donwline children

```
CREATE TABLE `treetbl` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `parentid` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `lft` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `rgt` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

**treetbl**

```
id      parentid       lft     rgt

1        1             1       1   

2        5             6       7

3        7             8       9
```

Here is my query to **Retrieving a Full Tree**

```
SELECT node.parentid,node.lft,node.rgt
FROM treetbl AS node,
        treetbl AS parent
WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt

ORDER BY node.lft;
```

but I am confuse how to filter the parentid example 5 to get all his down children.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to select only the records that have `parentid = 5`. **Am I right?**

If so and you say that this works for you with all entries:

```
SELECT node.parentid,node.lft,node.rgt FROM treetbl AS node, treetbl AS parent 
WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt ORDER BY node.lft;
```

, then why not just add `parentid = 5` with a help of `AND` statement to it? Like this:

```
SELECT node.parentid,node.lft,node.rgt FROM treetbl AS node, treetbl AS parent 
WHERE parentid = 5 AND node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
ORDER BY node.lft;
```

Of course, you can change that hard-coded `5` to some `$parentID` PHP variable.

Comment: it will only show 5 ,6, 7  the 8 and 9 are not 8 and 9 are children of 5

Comment: Yes, it will. Because you wanted to show only the elements that have `parentid = 5`, didn't you? If not, please expand your question so I can understand it better.

Answer (score -1):

maybe this is what you're looking for

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT node.parentid,node.lft,node.rgt
FROM treetbl AS node,
    treetbl AS parent
WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt

ORDER BY node.lft)A Where A.parentid>=5 ;
```

let me know if I am wrong